# Is there a tool that automatically inserts and updates a script header block for e.g. shell or Python scripts?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, utilities, programming

I found scripts by a former admin who scripted quite nice things with Bash or Python. All his scripts are well formatted and equipped with a always similar looking "script header" or "code header", I would call it.

I wonder how he did this and if maybe there is a well known tool out there what inserts and automatically updates these sorts of "code headers".

Any ideas / hints ?

Here is an example of such a code header block. It's not Python only. It was found in many languages and Linux scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8
#
#   project-name
#   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#
#   script description
#
#   * Intended to be run as a cron job.
#
#   Project title:      Back-Up Management
#
#   Project directory:  FileHost/project-name
#
#   Project documents:  xxxxx
#                       yyyyy
#                       zzzzz
#
#   Target OS:          Unix
#
#   Target interpreter: Python 2.5
#
#   File encoding:      UTF-8
#
#   2010-11-23  adminName     Created
#
#   2015-06-12  AdminName     CHANGE: some description
#
#   $Id: script-name.py 474 2010-12-10 12:16:36Z adminName $
#
```

Comment: It might be done by the editor (`emacs` or `vim`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the last line with text:

```
$Id: script-name.py 474 2010-12-10 12:16:36Z adminName $
```

you can assume that these files were kept in Subversion (there is an explanation of the `$Id$` keyword [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)). The older CVS would also use the `$Id$` keyword, but that would expand the filename to `script-name.py,v` (as is done [here](http://www.badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/keywords.html)).

The two entries before that could come from the revision history commit comments, although they look handcrafted as does the rest of the header.

I would search the machine for bash/python files that has a string like 
`Project title:` on a line that is not commented out. There is a good chance the former admin left his "tools" somewhere on the system.

Comment: Thanks Anthon, good hint. that leaded me to "svn" and a feature called "svn keyword substitution" http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.keywords It was an miss-assumption of mine that the whole header might be automaticaly created. it seems , as you mentioned, that most of the header is hand-crafted and somehow manualy added to new scripts. but the last line ($Id) is automatically updated by the "svn" client tool, if enabled in the svn project/repo. So, Question is SOLVED. thanks and greets Axel